# What power tool is the best and fastest to take up floor tile?

Tags: tile, floor, removal

I need to pull up the floor tile in my kitchen. i've tried using a hammer and chisel and the tile pops up easily, but it's too slow.
what power tool is the best and fastest to take up floor tile?
is there something with a spade that works well?

Answer (score 3):

A rotary hammer with sds plus attachments will likely serve you best.  These tools usually have three functions:  hammer (with a chisel bit for your purpose), rotating hammer (for drilling through concrete), and drill.  The tool plus the chisel attachment will run you about $300.  I've found mine very useful for the odd jobs of removing tiles and drilling for anchors.  They can be found widely at home improvement stores and online.

Comment: Many places rent tools like this although you might have to purchase the bits. After using this tool you can rent a rotary grinder with carbide teeth to take off the remaining thin-set mortar.

Comment: I've rented such a hammer at Home Depot for a day.   Worked well to remove stuborn tile on concrete in a bathroom.  Did not have to buy the bit/chisel.  Worth the money.

Answer (score 1):

we actually use a pair of shingle removers.  just shove under the tile, pry down and up pops the tile.  easier on the knees and back than a hammer.  two guys can rip out a kitchen floor in about an hour - even if there is lath under the floor.

http://www.roofersworld.com/red-ripperreg.html#.Vty2I_krKUk